# two with AND (&&) conditions in auraif

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-if

I have an `auraif` when I tried to use the condition And (`&&`) it points error:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.value == 'test' && v.recTypeName == 'testing'}">

</aura:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `and` expression function, as in:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{! and(equals(v.value, 'test'), equals(v.recTypeName, 'testing')) }">
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm

Comment: This does not work either

Comment: Thank you so much I had tried in a very similar way. But without success kk

Comment: Please update your original question with the error message, and make sure that both values you are using in the condition are set.

Comment: I've edited my answer to use the `equal` function as well. If it still throws you an error, it is likely a problem outside this expression.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are trying to use `&&` and getting error, then that's expected. Using `&&` is not allowed in components. You will need to use `&amp;&amp;` in that case.

However, it is recommended that you use `and(condition)`. This is from [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm):

> `&amp;&amp;`
>   This syntax is awkward in markup so we recommend using the `and` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do your calculations in a javascript controller and write the result to an aura attribute

**Component Markup**

```
<aura:component>
    <!-- Attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recTypeName" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="testValue" type="Boolean"/>
    <aura:attribute name="testRecType" type="Boolean"/>

    <!-- Initialize event to handle calculating the boolean values-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
```

**JS Controller**

```js
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.testValue', (component.get('v.value') == 'test'));
        //similar syntax for the recTypeName
    }
})
```

Then your initializer will run every time the component begins. Or you can code a similar calculation in some other function for more frequent updates

You can use the aura:if and isTrue attribute as follows:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.testValue, v.testRecType)}">

</aura:if>
```

Comment: The operators do work in aura expressions, though.

Comment: Thanks, edited.